# Add options to WordPress Blocks form dropdown field

Tags: forms, dropdown, select

How can I add additional options to the WordPress Blocks form dropdown field? I only see the one option field and can't figure out how to add more.

Comment: By “WordPress Blocks form dropdown field” what are you referring to? That’s very vague.